# Create list with group members in one column

Tags: 2013, list, groups

How do I create a list, that holds the names of the group members in one column and some more columns for other information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first you need to create a list [List creation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-in-SharePoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in the sharepoint 2013  and Need to create a column of type Person or Group. After that you need to set the options for  the column as per you requirement

**Allow multiple selections**    Allow people to select as many options as they like or limit the number of selections to only one option.

**Include or exclude groups of people**    Specify whether the list includes only individual people, or additionally includes e-mail distribution lists and SharePoint groups. For example, on a Tasks list, you might want to include only individual people to ensure that a specific person is responsible for each task. On a Projects list, you might want to include e-mail distribution lists and SharePoint groups to ensure that a team is associated with each project.

**Limit the list to site users only**    Specify whether the list includes all people and groups in the directory service or only those people and groups who have access to the site as members of a SharePoint group.

**Specify which information to display**    Choose which information you want to display about people or groups. For example, on a Contacts list for a large organization, you might choose to display a person's name, picture, and details such as skills and expertise. On a Contacts list for a small team, you might choose to display only a person's name or e-mail address.

please check the below for more details   for creating different types of column types and their options

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7